# Prevent line breaks before short math expressions globally

Tags: math-mode, line-breaking

Is there a way to globally prevent line breaks before math expression that are a single letter ?

For example, in a document I have

```
\begin{lemma}
An edge $\lambda_{xy}$ is identifiable in a tree graph $\mathcal{G}$, 
if (and only if) the system of the equations 
...
```

[image]

which does not look nice. I would prefer it to look like
[image]

I know I can write

```
\begin{lemma}
An edge $\lambda_{xy}$ is identifiable in a tree graph~$\mathcal{G}$, 
if (and only if) the system of the equations 
...
```

But there are too many of these equations in the document to put a `~` everywhere. And that makes the tex file look not nice.

I would like to change the line break algorithm such that the first code snippet is rendered like the second picture.

Comment: a ~ is only one character as is a space, is it so much harder to type? (I suppose it may be if you use a keyboard where it isn't easily available, but you could use a different character)